# No accepted answers so far

Tags: discussion

We need a model of question that can have real answers.  While a teacher community is a wonderful (and very sorely needed!) thing, how can we encourage questions that have actual answers?

**Edit:** Alternatively, seeing how things are shaping up a bit now, perhaps this is as it should be. Looking at [matheducators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/), it appears that answers are only accepted when appropriate.  Is this a better model for us?

Comment: I just had a similar interesting discussion about the scope of the site [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/computer-science-educators). Would anyone mind weighing in, from a more professional perspective?

Comment: I asked a question but now i don't know how to accept and answer without being biased. I will wait another day and choose the most popular one that I believe makes sense, perhaps.

Comment: @ecc Don't worry about being 'biased'; the whole point of an accepted answer is the one that *you* like the most, and that you find most helpful. Obviously, when they're equally good, it's hard to decide—in that case, you can just go by votes, or whatever you want; there aren't any specific rules.

Answer (score 5):

There should be no rush to accept an answer within a few hours. Unless the answer is definitive, waiting 12 hours or so gives more people encouragement to contribute.